# Grails 4 IDE otherthan Intellij Ultimate

Tags: grails, ide

what is the IDE for developing Grails 4 application? with grails 2, we are using GGTS. we are going to upgrade it to v4. GGTS is not supported, so what will be the alternative IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intellj Community Edition which is free.  You just lose up on a couple of nice things from Ultimate?

Community Edition is free to use for personal and commercial development. The IDE and most of it bundled plugins are open-source, licensed under Apache 2.0.